# Aligning a div vertically middle

Tags: html, css

I want my red rectangle in the middle of the number, for this I have added a wrapper `div` with style `display:table` and for `box div` style is `display:table-cell, vertical-align:middle`. Following is my html

```html
<div class="repeat_div" style="border-right: 0px solid rgb(158, 158, 158); padding: 0px 15px; float: left;">
  <div class="topLabel" style="margin-left: 25px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: rgb(158, 158, 158); background-color: transparent;"><span>Youtube Top</span></div>
  <div class="boxStatsContainer" style="float: left;">
    <div style="float: left; display:table">
      <div class="box" style="float: left; background-color: rgb(235, 134, 79); width: 15px; height: 20px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stats" style="font-size: 48px; float: left; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: black;"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">$620</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomLabel" style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 25px; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: rgb(158, 158, 158);"><span>Youtube</span></div>
</div>
```

But red box is not in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align : middle` to make it work.

```html
<div class="repeat_div" style="border-right: 0px solid rgb(158, 158, 158); padding: 0px 15px; float: left;">
  <div class="topLabel" style="margin-left: 25px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: rgb(158, 158, 158); background-color: transparent;"><span>Youtube Top</span></div>
  <div class="boxStatsContainer" style="float: left;">
    <div style="float: none; display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
      <div class="box" style="float: left; background-color: rgb(235, 134, 79); width: 15px; height: 20px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stats" style="font-size: 48px; float: none;display: table-cell;    vertical-align: middle; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: black;"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">$620</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomLabel" style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 25px; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: rgb(158, 158, 158);"><span>Youtube</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `display: flex; align-items: center` to your `boxStatsContainer` div element;

```html
<div class="repeat_div" style="border-right: 0px solid rgb(158, 158, 158); padding: 0px 15px; float: left;">
  <div class="topLabel" style="margin-left: 25px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: rgb(158, 158, 158); background-color: transparent;"><span>Youtube Top</span></div>
  <div class="boxStatsContainer" style="float: left; display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <div style="float: left; display:table">
      <div class="box" style="float: left; background-color: rgb(235, 134, 79); width: 15px; height: 20px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stats" style="font-size: 48px; float: left; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: black;"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">$620</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomLabel" style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 25px; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: rgb(158, 158, 158);"><span>Youtube</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` for center.

```html
<div class="repeat_div" style="border-right: 0px solid rgb(158, 158, 158); padding: 0px 15px; float: left;">
  <div class="topLabel" style="margin-left: 25px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: rgb(158, 158, 158); background-color: transparent;"><span>Youtube Top</span></div>
  <div class="boxStatsContainer" style="float: left;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
      <div class="box" style=" float:left;background-color: rgb(235, 134, 79); width: 15px; height: 20px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stats" style="font-size: 48px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: black;"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">$620</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomLabel" style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 25px; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; text-transform: none; color: rgb(158, 158, 158);"><span>Youtube</span></div>
</div>
```